# Most efficient way to take max width of multiple views and set that as width of all said views?

Tags: swift

What is the most efficient way (least amount of lines of code) to take the widths of a list of views, find the greatest value, and set that value as the width of those views? This example uses if/else for 2 views (to help illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish) but what if there were 3 or 30 views?

```
let label1Width = label1.bounds.width
let label2Width = label2.bounds.width

if label1Width > label2Width {
    label2.frame.size.width = label1Width
}

if label2Width > label1Width {
    label1.frame.size.width = label2Width
}
```

Comment: "efficient" and "least amount of lines of code" do not mean the same thing. Write readable, maintainable code. Worry about efficiency only when you actually have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max(by:)` to find the element of an array with a maximum value where you define the comparison function yourself. In this case, you would use `.frame.size.width` for comparison.

Once you find the maximum width, you can just iterate through all your labels and assign the maximum width to each label.

Below code has been tested in a playground and is working as expected.

```
let labels = [UILabel(),UILabel(),UILabel(),UILabel(),UILabel(),UILabel(),UILabel(),UILabel(),UILabel(),UILabel()]
labels[3].frame.size.width = 100
labels[5].frame.size.width = 200
let maxWidth = labels.max(by: {$0.0.frame.size.width < $0.1.frame.size.width})!.frame.size.width
labels.forEach{
    $0.frame.size.width = maxWidth!
}
```

Print the width values for testing:

```
labels.forEach{
    print($0.frame.size.width) //prints 200 for each element of the array
}
```

Comment: FYI - your labels array is going to contain 10 references to a single instance of `UILabel` (because it's a class, not a struct). All labels will have the same width of 200 before you call `labels.max`. While this answer shows a good way to find and set the max width to all labels, the setup code doesn't verify the code actually works properly.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the input, I didn't even think about the behaviour of `Array(repeating:)` for reference types. Updated my answer to make the test data work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a max function, eg:

`let maxWidth = max(label1.bounds.width, label2.bounds.width)`

Comment: But the question is asking what to do when there are 30 views, not 2.

Comment: `max()` takes a variable amount of arguments.